# Python: interpreter says "None" after parsing file

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, interpreter

I've written a simple interpreter with Python for a programming language I've created. I have a little problem though: when I try to read a file, so the code can be interpreted, Python says `None`.

Here's the interpreter code:

```
import sys

class Interpret:
    def read(self, cmd):
        tokens = cmd.split("\n")
        for i in range(0, len(tokens)):
            self.parse(tokens[i])

    def parse(self, cmd):
        if cmd.startswith("print(") and cmd.endswith(")"):
            cmd = cmd[6:]
            cmd = cmd[:-1]
            return(cmd)

interpret = Interpret()

code = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
print(interpret.read(str(code)))
```

Here's the code in the file I want to read: `print(Hi)\n` (Yes, there's a newline there, not the characters `\n`)

So, here's what happened in CMD:

```
> python interpreter.py test.tl

None
```

It should output `Hi`, but it doesn't work properly. I think it has something to do with the last two lines of the interpreter code, but I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your problems is this line:

```
code = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
```

`open` returns a file object, not the content of the file. Instead, do:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    code = f.read()
```

---

On to the next issue:

```
for i in range(0, len(tokens)):
    self.parse(tokens[i])
```

There is no reason to iterate over the `range` of a `len`, ever. Just iterate over the tokens:

```
for token in tokens:
    self.parse(token)
```

---

That your code prints `None` is (as ForceBru has written already) due to the fact that you're printing the return value of a method that returns nothing. Just call `interpret.read(str(code))` directly, without wrapping `print` around it.

---

After applying all these fixes, to make your code work either do what ForceBru says and `yield self.parse(token)`, or, for testing purposes just `print` inside of `parse`:

```
def parse(self, cmd):
    if cmd.startswith("print(") and cmd.endswith(")"):
        cmd = cmd[6:]
        cmd = cmd[:-1]
        print(cmd)
```

Then, your code works for me with `print(Hi)\n` in the `test.tl` file.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and also for the extra tips :)

Answer (score 3):

You're just *calling* `self.parse` and not using its return value and, given that `self.parse` doesn't output anything and `read` returns nothing (`None`), you're getting `None` as a result.

You may want your `read` to `yield self.parse(tokens[i])` on each iteration, thus making it a generator, and then do something like this:

```
for data in interpret.read(str(code)):
    print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)